# Does Facebook Mobile Application call Graph API directly?

Tags: web-api, android-development

Does anyone know that Facebook mobile application is using their Graph API directly? or they create another layer specifically for handle their mobile application?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us why you're interested in knowing this information? It's not that there's anything wrong with it, but we might be able to suggest a more secure alternative, if we know a little more about why you're asking.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard The reason is I want to learn a practical way that facebook internally manage their API, specifically with their mobile application, how they release API for their mobile app, how they manage changes in APIs and maintain their old clients, how they structure API endpoints and schemas.

Maybe there is something I would learn from their success to apply to my project.

It would be great if you can help.

Comment: Very good points. As I don't work for Facebook, I can't give a solid answer. Although a qualified guess would be that the Facebook and Messenger App likely has their own API endpoints, in which some of them may be simple redirects to the Graph API. I base this on the fact that the apps has many features which can be accessed via the Graph API, but also many which cannot. But like I said, it's pure guessing.